# How to write Lagrangian of field with vector and scalar potential

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

I am beginner of quantum field theory. I have a basic question.

Lagrangian of a electron in the potential has the form of

$${1\over2}m{\bf v}^2-e\Phi+e \bf v \cdot A$$

Lagrangian in quantum field theory with $\psi(x)$ is

$$L=\int dx ( {1\over2}\nabla\psi^*\nabla\psi-e\Phi \psi\psi^*+.. )$$

How the third term, $e \bf v \cdot A$ should be written?

Comment: Your first Lagrangian is that of a non relativistic, charged particle in an E.M. field. The second one is a charged K.G. field which is relativistic. Therefore the two are unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to learn that the $4$-potential is intimately connected with the process of taking derivatives. So, you begin with a Lagrangian that doesn't have an E&M interaction. For what you have written, the Lagrangian is
$$ L = \int \mathrm{d}x \ \frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu \psi)^* \partial^\mu \psi,$$
assuming the metric signature is $(+,-,-,-)$. The non covariant way to write this is:
$$ L = \int \mathrm{d}x \ \frac{1}{2} \partial_t \psi^* \partial_t \psi - \frac{1}{2} \nabla \psi^* \cdot\nabla \psi.$$

The way to turn on E&M interactions is to do the substitution $\partial_\mu \rightarrow \partial_\mu - i e A_\mu$. Doing that substitution and expanding yields
$$ L = \int \mathrm{d}x \ \frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu \psi)^* \partial^\mu \psi + ieA_\mu \psi^* \partial^\mu - ie (\partial_\mu\psi)^* A^\mu \psi + e^2 A_\mu \psi^* A^\mu \psi \psi.$$
Note first: the charge density/"scalar" potential term are the $A^0$ terms, and the vector potential terms are the ones with $A^{1,2,3}$.

There's also a completely new terms that is quadratic in $A$, and this is unique to scalar type fields. To get what you're expecting, an analogue to the classical $J^\mu A_\mu$, you need to use a Lagrangian more like the [Dirac one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermionic_field#Dirac_fields), not what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $-e\Phi+e\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{A}$ you will have something like $-j_\mu A^\mu$, where $j^\mu=i e(\psi^*\psi_{,\mu}-\psi^*_{,\mu})-2 e^2 A_\mu\psi^*\psi$.